# Angular parent to child communication passing empty data

Tags: angular, typescript

Parent is creating view with *ngFor. In every loops repeat name of current part of view is changing and passing to child. Child gets empty variable name.

PARENT:
HTML:

```
<div *ngFor ="let name of statisticsName">
 <app-progress-table [name]="name"></app-progress-table>
</div>
```

Child:
TS:

```
 @Input() name: string;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.processDataSource = this.selectDataSource(name);
 }

 selectDataSource(optionName: string){}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="processDataSource">
</mat-table>
```

Method is based on multiple conditional instructions and using "name" from parent always is using last "else" instruction cause "name" is empty.

I expect that "name" variable will have assigned the current one from "statisticsName".

Comment: Can you create a stackbiltz and share

Comment: Can you post sample data of statisticsName array

Comment: Is your `statisticsName` really an array of strings and not an array of objects with the property `name`? Also, can you try  merging your code snippets and have 2 big snippets for each file instead of scattering them? It's easier to read understand :)

Comment: statisticsName : string[] =["1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ]; - thats how declaration looks like

Comment: About stackblitz - project and both of components are very complex and I would need a lot of time to important to works on blitz.

Comment: can you please update sample data for `name`? I think this is data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [angular LifeCycle Hooks section](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) of the [angular Documentations](https://angular.io/docs).
I believe that a ngOnChanges() Hook is more suitable for the functionality that you are looking for, as you might get the Inputed Variable as it is instantiated of in the begining of the ngOnInit Lifecycle hook and not passed in the check that ngOnChanges provides.
Read below as it was copied from the Documentation site:

```
ngOnChanges()
```

Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.

Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem by using method before calling child, which assigns data to the variable being passed.

```
{{getStatisticsName(name)}}
<app-progress-table [nameFromParent]="nameToChild"></app-progress-table>
```